# mapbox layer in ESRI API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cartography, mapbox

I am building an application primarily with the ESRI API, but would like to load a mapbox tilelayer to use as the basemap as they are just so much more pleasing cartographically. I dont want to change the actual "map", as I need many of the widgets that need this tag to load and function correctly.  was thinking of simply loading the mapbox tiles and addinn them to the map.  Following the mapbox API documentation, I loaded the library:

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.2/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.2/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

I then tried to create the layer of the map box tiles and add that to the map:

```
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.ID');
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Doing this I get two related errors.

1 - GET http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.ID.json 404 (Not Found)
2 - could not load TileJSON at http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.ID.json

What am I missing

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify the value of "mapbox.ID" for the tile set you want to load. In the API docs they show an example successful URL:

http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zr0njcqy.json

Comment: I follow what you are saying, but the reference is confusing.  Do I need to add the lines: ["http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zr0njcqy/{z}/{x}/{y}.png","http://b.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zr0njcqy/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"]?

Comment: It's hard to tell where you might be stuck as your example looks more like Leaflet than ESRI JSAPI. Maybe your simplest path is to register the Mapbox layer you want to use in ArcGIS.com and then use it like any other layer you would connect to from ArcGIS.com. Looking at this link might help: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/04/01/using-stamen-and-mapbox-tilesets-as-basemaps-in-arcgis-com/